# Block specific IP for a number of minutes after 10 connections

Tags: iptables, ftp

I am writing some code that makes connections to a host, and if the host blocks a connection, it sleeps for a predetermined amount of time, before trying again.

Basically I need Ubuntu to allow 10 ftp connections from a specific ip, then block any attempts for 10 minutes then re-allow connections from that IP address again.

How can I do that?

Comment: Not looking to ban due to incorrect password attempts, but rather limiting the number of consecutive anonymous connections from a given IP address.

Comment: I only know how to do it easily with iptables, using the `recent` module, if the 10 connections are over a specified time (and the same same timeout duration and 10 connections time is by far easiest).

Comment: @ADDB: Please read the question again! OP wants to establish connections to a server that throttles connection attempts, not throttle connection attempts made to their own server.

Comment: This is a programming question which is off topic on Ask Ubuntu. It's also unclear how you establishing connections currently.